# 404 error when running a GWT program in Eclipse. Seems to be to do with servlet mapping

Tags: eclipse, gwt, servlets

I have a GWT project which has been working fine for many weeks. On opening the code yesterday I found dozens of big red errors in my code. I've seen this happen before and have learnt, after much frustration, that all I need to is clean the project for Eclipse to be happy again, so I did that. Fine.

However, when I run the thing, I get a 404 error saying this:
type Status report
message /LittleRedGarden/littleredgarden/greet
description The requested resource (/LittleRedGarden/littleredgarden/greet) is not available.

The message gets written in HTML in the console in Eclipse.

I'll insert my web.xml file in full at the bottom, but it seems to point to the paths mentioned above ok. I should say that the web.xml file was built by Eclipse without any supervision from me, and as I say, has been working fine until now.

Where do I start looking for a solution to this?

Thanks. web.xml contents here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ducksstory.littleredgarden.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/littleredgarden/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>LittleRedGarden.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

---

Here's GreetingService.java:

```
package com.ducksstory.littleredgarden.client;

import com.ducksstory.littleredgarden.shared.QuestionStrings;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

/**
 * The client side stub for the RPC service.
 */
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("greet")
public interface GreetingService extends RemoteService
{
    String greetServer(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException;
    QuestionStrings getQuestion(int i);
    String[] getMainImages();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've fixed this just by restarting Eclipse. What a waste of time! Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Upto my knowledge there is no pbm with your web.xml file. But you may check with your service file written in the client package. In your case your service file name should be GreetingService.java . Check in that file whether you are used the proper annotation

> @RemoteServiceRelativePath("greet")

If this one also fine with your file then you can download a sample gwt project and do the comparison. Correct me if i'm wrong..

Comment: Thanks for trying. I'll add the contents of GreetingService.java, & you'll see that it corresponds to what you say. As for sample projects, I have several working projects (and remember, this was one last time I closed Eclipse), and I can't see any obvious differences between them and this. But I don't know where to look!