# Why does GWT in Eclipse always shows an Error 404?

Tags: java, gwt

I don't know why, but now every project that I run on local shows on Firefox 'Error 404'.

When I access to the url that Eclipse gave me, in console shows:

```
24-jul-2013 18:09:45 com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /WhereIsMatch.html
```

I've also tried to run the sample projects (Import App Engine Sample Apps...). Even they don't run.

So, what could be wrong in Eclipse?

Comment: What is the exact error log , how are you trying to access it !

Comment: @The New Idiot
24-jul-2013 18:09:45 com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
ADVERTENCIA: No file found for: /WhereIsMatch.html

How can I access it?

Comment: [Help us help you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I would suggest you to go throught this :-
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716579/404-error-when-running-a-gwt-program-in-eclipse-seems-to-be-to-do-with-servlet
Hope it helps!!

Comment: @JohnSnow But I've also tried to run the sample projects. I supposed they must run right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I thinked I restarted eclipse before, but it seems I didn't. I've restarted eclipse and this problem was solved.